# React Native svg url gives error

Tags: javascript, ios, svg, react-native, react-native-ios

I am creating a component for input boxes. As such I am trying to have them use a left icon etc.

Here's the code I am using:

```
  <View
    style={[styles.enclosingBox, this.props.style]}>
    {this.props.drawableLeft && 
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.props.drawableLeftClick || (() => {})}>
        <SvgUri width="24" height="24" source={require(this.props.drawableLeft)} resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.contain} />
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    }
    <TextInput autoFocus={this.props.autoFocus || false}
      keyboardType={this.props.keyboardType || 'default'}
      maxLength={this.props.maxLength}
      placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
      style={[styles.textStyle, {color: config.colors.primary}, this.props.textStyle]}
      onChangeText={this.props.onChangeText}>
    </TextInput>
    {this.props.drawableRight && 
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.props.drawableRightClick || (() => {})}>
        <SvgUri width="24" height="24" source={require(this.props.drawableRight)} resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.contain} />
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    }
  </View>
```

When I am using this component like this:

{}} />

It results in this error: [image]

If I hardcode the path to the svg file in the component though, it works just fine. Any ideas on what may be happening here?

Comment: You need to use the following module for to display SVG by path
https://github.com/matc4/react-native-svg-uri

Comment: @NisargThakkar That's what I am using! If you see the tag it's the one from that module!